# Contentful images not showing in Facebook in-app browser

Tags: facebook

Images loaded via `<img>` or background-image CSS URL from Contentful CMS don't show in Facebook's in-app browser e.g:

`"//images.ctfassets.net/yadj1kx9rmg0/wtrHxeu3zEoEce2MokCSi/cf6f68efdcf625fdc060607df0f3baef/quwowooybuqbl6ntboz3.jpg"`

...with Https hosting, and load in all other modern browsers, but not FB in app browser

I'm thinking it's a mixed content problem, but don't see how?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to programatically add `https:` to the beginning of the image URL. It is called a [protocol relative URL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Protocol-relative_URL) and it'll work with most websites by automatically taking the protocol of the page that contains it but I guess it doesn't work for Facebook

Comment: The _current_ form is protocol relative - if you add `https:` in front of it, it is _not_ relative any more, but absolute. _Because_ it is a protocol relative URL, it _can’t_ cause mixed content warnings in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe It doesn't work on Android, with either protocol relative (which I'm already using) or absolute paths. I've seen it happening with my own tests and also when testing other websites that I know use Contentful images (they don't load). I think it's specific to Android, as I have seen the same sites working fine on iPhones

Comment: @Dave then it is probably not a real mixed content issue to begin with. Might be that an intermediate certificate is missing (which other systems might have “on board” per default), or maybe an issue with the ddos protection - images.ctfassets.net seems to resolve to servers under cloudfront’s control, so it might also be an issue in that regard perhaps; they might simply say “nope” if they can not verify those requests coming from Android devices as “genuine” for some reason.